# How to allow users to submit WOL requests through an internal site?

Tags: wake-on-lan

I've been asked to set up a system where a user can visit an internal website from one domain, submit the name of the PC they'd like turned on in another domain, then the server sends a WOL Packet to that PC (through running a program like wolcmd?).

At the moment all of our PC's are set to turn on in the morning before people start working so that they can remote into their PC's from home without someone needing to be there to turn it on, however this is a waste of electricity, especially when the PC isn't being used that day.

How would you set up a system like this? I've tried looking for a similar problem but failed to find one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write a web app that does exactly this, and hopefully checks for some kind of authentication. Wake-on-lan is really just a specific packet, you can send it from pretty much any program.

One possible solution would be to write a Django or Flask app which authenticates the user and then sends a WOL packet using [wakeonlan](https://pypi.org/project/wakeonlan/).

Comment: Node-Red has a module for this.

Comment: The one thing to keep in mind is that the magic packet "sender" will need to be in the same network segment as the target.  In other words, they'll employ the same broadcast address and reside in the same IP space (e.g.. 192.168.1.0 thru 192.168.1.254 with 255.255.255.0, or 172.16.0.0-172.16.255.255 with 255.255.0.0, or 10.0.0.0 thru 10.255.255.254 with 255.0.0.0).